# A question asking to prove an array is not a Latin square

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, latin-square

I am trying exercises of Ch. 10 of *Combinatorics* by Richard Brualdi, and I am struck on this question.

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $r$ be a nonzero integer in $Z_n$ such that $\gcd(r, n)\ne 1$ . Show that array $A$ consructed as $a_{i,j}  = r \times i+j \pmod n$ is not a Latin square .

I am thinking to show that two values in some row or column are same, which will prove that it's  not a Latin square. So, I choose $a_{i, j} = r\times i + j +kn$ and trying to prove $it = r× i+ m + k'n Or = r×l + j + k"n$ but I am unable to implement this approach. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, if someone has another method to solve that too is equally good.

Comment: You're almost there. What would it take for $ a_{i, j } \equiv a_{i, m } \pmod {n}$? __Hint:__ You haven't used $\gcd(r,n) \neq 1$.

Comment: @CalvinLin can you please tell how to use gcd(r, n) $\neq$1 ?  I am unable to deduce.

Comment: Can you share your work? E.g. When do we have $a_{i,j} \equiv a_{i,m}$?

Comment: @CalvinLin showing of work -> $a_{i, j} $ = r×i + j +k n. I am thinking of proving it to be equal to = r× q + j +k' n or similar for columns if not able to prove it for row. I tried by adding and subtracting d but that also doesn't seems to help.Can you please tell now?

Comment: Are there solutions to $ ri \equiv j - m \pmod{n}, where $ j \neq m$?

Comment: @Calvin Lin assuming I to be variable, as gcd (d n) $\neq$ 1 and it must divide j-m  and -(n-1) $\leq $ j-m$ \leq $ (n-1) and j$\neq$ n. So, I think j- m could be choosen so as d | j-m if d $\neq$  n, so solution doesn't exists always ( case gcd (r, n) =d) . So, I think solution don't exists always.

Comment: @Calvin Lin can you please help with an answer.Otherwise I have to put a bounty on this question . I don't think this question deserves 50 points when you are saying I am almost there.

Comment: Just do it. E.g. Write out the table say for $ n = 6, r = 2$. Do you get a Latin square? If no, what's preventing it from being a Latin square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what we get for $n = 6, r = 2$.

[image]

The reasonable guess is that a column would get repeats, hence isn't a Latin square.

Can you prove that?

---

> Let $\gcd (r,n) = d > 1$, so $ r = da, n = db$.
>  Then, $ r_{i,j} \equiv r_{i+b,j } \pmod{n}.$

Comment: Lin. I deduced that $a_{i, j} $ = $a_{i, k} $ can never happen. But $a_{i, j} $ = $ a_{k, j} $ can always happen. So, resultant array will not be a Latin square. Hope I am right now?

Comment: @TimGreen Yes..